# Python3 - default keyword for default values for type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does Python3 have anything like the [`default` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) from .NET? That is, given a type, it produces a value of that type that is normally referred to as the default value for it.  E.g.:

`default(int)` is `0`

`default(decimal)` is `0.0`

`default(MyCustomClassType)` is `null`

I am hoping such a thing already exists, as I would like to pre-process the values from a pandas dataframe and replace the NaNs with 0 for integer columns etc, and avoid writing my own function (containing a giant switch for each possible type, to mimic the behaviour I exemplified earlier, from .NET).

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `int()` returns `0` by default and `float()` returns `0.0` by default. Does this help?

Comment: @idjaw, and does `x = something or int()` not fulfil the same need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments, Python types such as `int`, `float`, `str`, `list`, etc. are all callable, i.e. you can use `int()` and get `0`, or `str()` and `list()` and get an empty string or list.

```
>>> type(42)()
0
```

The same also holds for `numpy` types. You can get the type of a numpy array using the `dtype` attribute, and then use that to initialize the "missing" values:

```
>>> A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, float("nan")]) # common type is float64
>>> A
array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,  nan])
>>> A[np.isnan(A)] = A.dtype.type() # nan is replaced with 0.0
>>> A
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  0.])
>>> B = np.array([1, 2, 3, -1, 5]) # common type is int64
>>> B
array([ 1,  2,  3, -1,  5])
>>> B[B == -1] = B.dtype.type() # -1 is replaced with 
>>> B
array([1, 2, 3, 0, 5])
```

This also works with other classes that provide a no-args-constructor, however, the result will be an instance of that class, not `null` as in your example..

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
>>> type(Foo())()
<__main__.Foo at 0x7f8b124c00d0>
```

Comment: That is excellent, exactly what I was looking for, thank you.